# Why does this regexp work insanely slow?

Tags: python, regex, performance

Any idea why does this statement runs **very** slow (about 5 hours in my previous test)

```
re.sub('(?i)\(\s*poziom\s*:?(\s*[\wśą-]+)+\s*\)','','(poziom: średniozaawansowany testtesttestąą ()')
```

while this one finishes in sensible time:

```
re.sub('(?i)\(\s*poziom\s*:?(\s*[\wśą-]+)+\s*\)','','(poziom: średniozaawansowany testtesttestąą )')
```

? The difference is missing opening bracket at last but one position in second statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(\s*[\wśą-]+)+
```

See how this part has a repetition operator around repetition operators? That'll go through every possible way to group the non-whitespace characters into runs of 1 or more. You might instead try something like

```
[\s\wśą-]+
```

The first one takes forever because the `(` makes the match fail, so it has to spend exponential time backtracking, hoping that maybe one of the other grouping possibilities will make a match. The second one finds a match immediately and doesn't have to do the exponential backtracking.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it had sth in common with non-ascii characters (ąę), but after your answer I realized it works exactly the same without these characters.